# Python and VS code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, error-handling, python-exec

I am trying to run code in VSCode but every time getting an error that I could not resolve.

Here is the error:

```txt
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again !!
```

Could you help me to resolve this?

I Added Python path (ex `C:/Users/pv/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe`) to the `%PATH%` env variable even reinstalled the python and vscode. both are not working for me

Comment: Add program directory to path, not the program's full path, ie:  add `C:/Users/pv/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/` to `%PATH%`

Comment: read the Python doc pages for VSC

Comment: It is resolved!! @mislah Thank you so much for answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, you're supposed to add the path to a directory containing binaries to the environment `PATH`- not the path to the binary itself. Ex `C:/Users/pv/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38`.